# javascript not updating the text of p tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a simple game using `html`, `css` and `javascript`. Image of the game interface is shown below[image]

**Working of this game**

In this game, each player, on his turn, rolls the dice. The number on the dice gets added to current player's `current score`. Each player rolls dice until dice rolls to `1` or if the player clicks on `hold score` label.

If dice rolls to `1`, current player's `current score` becomes `0`. During his turn, any player can choose to `hold score` which will add that player's `current score` to his `total score`, displayed above the `current score`, and the then next player takes his turn.

First player whose total score becomes equal to or greater than `100`, wins. Any player's victory is indicated by `alert` method of `javascript`.

## Problem

**Example case :**

Consider a case where `player 1`'s `total score` is `95` and then `player 1` rolls the dice and the dice rolls to `5`. Now `player 1` chooses to `hold score`, so `player 1`'s `total score` and `current score` should add up and the `total score` should become `100` and then the alert is generated indicating that `player 1 has won`. **Problem** is that, when any player's total score gets equal or greater than `100`, alert is generated correctly but before generating the alert, that player's `total score` should update which doesn't happens.

**PS.** When the `total score` is not greater than or equal to 100 for any player, that player's `total score` updates without any problem. Problem only seem to arise when `total score` becomes greater than or equal to `100`

**Need help** to identify what's causing this issue.

Following code is responsible for updating each player's total score when player chooses to `hold score`

```
document.getElementById('hold-score-label').onclick = function () {

    //take current score and add it to total score of current player
    var playerTotalScore = document.getElementById('player'+playerTurn+'-dice-roll-score');
    playerTotalScore.textContent = currentScoreVal + parseInt(playerTotalScore.textContent);

    //set current score of current player to zero
    document.getElementById('p'+playerTurn+'-current-score-value').textContent = 0;

    //CHECK IF ANY PLAYER HAS WON
    if(parseInt(playerTotalScore.textContent) >= 100) {
        checkWin(playerTurn);
    }

    //change player turn
    changePlayerTurn();
};
```

Complete Javascript code

```
var playerTurn = 1;   //1 indicates current turn is of player1
var currentScoreVal = 0; //variable to store current score for "hold score" click event

//HIDE THE PLAYER TURN IMAGE OF PLAYER 2
document.getElementById('player2-turn-img').style.display = 'none';

//ADD ACTIVE CLASS TO PLAYER1
document.getElementById('main-container').classList.add('activePlayer1');

//SET CLICK LISTNER FOR 'ROLL DICE' LABEL
document.getElementById('roll-dice-label').onclick = function() {

    var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    document.getElementById('dice-image').src = "Images/dice"+randomNum+".png";
    setScores(randomNum, playerTurn);
};

//FUNCTION THAT UPDATES CURRENT PLAYER'S SCORES
//RANDOM NUMBER GENERATED IN PREVIOUS FUNCTION IS PASSED AS ARGUMENT TO THIS FUNCTION
//CURRENT PLAYER TURN IS ALSO PASSED TO THIS FUNCTION
function setScores (diceNumber , currentPlayer) {

    //GET HTML ELEMENT OF CURRENT SCORE BASED ON CURRENT PLAYER
    var currentScore = document.getElementById('p'+currentPlayer+'-current-score-value');

    //GET HTML ELEMENT OF TOTAL SCORE BASED ON CURRENT PLAYER
    var diceRollScore = document.getElementById('player'+currentPlayer+'-dice-roll-score');

    if(diceNumber > 1) {
        currentScoreVal = parseInt(currentScore.textContent) + diceNumber;
        currentScore.textContent = currentScoreVal;
    }
    else {
        //SET CURRENT SCORE OF CURRENT PLAYER TO ZERO
        currentScore.textContent = 0;

        changePlayerTurn();
    }
}

//FUNCTION TO CHECK IF CURRENT PLAYER'S SCORE IS GREATER THAN 100 OR NOT
function checkWin(currentPlayer) {
    alert('Player '+ currentPlayer +' has won');
    resetGame();
}

//FUNCTION THAT RESETS GAME TO ITS INITIAL STATE
function resetGame() {
    //reset the current player turn indicator image
    document.getElementById('player1-turn-img').style.display = "inline-block";
    document.getElementById('player2-turn-img').style.display = 'none';

    //set dice image to 'dice1.png'
    document.getElementById('dice-image').src = "images/dice1.png";

    //set current scores of both players to zero
    document.getElementById('p1-current-score-value').textContent = 0;
    document.getElementById('p2-current-score-value').textContent = 0;

    //set total score of both players to zero
    document.getElementById('player1-dice-roll-score').textContent = 0;
    document.getElementById('player2-dice-roll-score').textContent = 0;

    //set active player background color to player1 panel
    document.getElementById('main-container').classList.remove('activePlayer2');
    document.getElementById('main-container').classList.add('activePlayer1');
}

//CLICK LISTNER FOR HOLD SCORE LABEL
document.getElementById('hold-score-label').onclick = function () {

    //take current score and add it to total score of current player
    var playerTotalScore = document.getElementById('player'+playerTurn+'-dice-roll-score');playerTotalScore.textContent = currentScoreVal + parseInt(playerTotalScore.textContent);

    //set current score of current player to zero
    document.getElementById('p'+playerTurn+'-current-score-value').textContent = 0;

    //CHECK IF ANY PLAYER HAS WON
    if(parseInt(playerTotalScore.textContent) >= 100) {
        checkWin(playerTurn);
    }

    //change player turn
    changePlayerTurn();
};

//FUNCTION TO CHANGE CURRENT PLAYER TURN
function changePlayerTurn() {
    if(playerTurn === 1) {
        playerTurn = 2;
        document.getElementById('main-container').classList.add('activePlayer2');
        document.getElementById('player1-turn-img').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('player2-turn-img').style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
    else {
        playerTurn = 1;
        document.getElementById('main-container').classList.remove('activePlayer2');
        document.getElementById('player1-turn-img').style.display = "inline-block";
        document.getElementById('player2-turn-img').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

**You can test this game yourself :** [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eeMgjR)

Please note that images shown in the interface above wont show. So dice image wont show but it will update score values when you click on `roll dice` label.

Comment: Can you make a [mcve]? Will be really helpful to debug if you can reproduce the issue. Also did you check the console for any errors?

Comment: added the codepen link

Comment: I have seen a lot places you have added `textContent`. Can you try replacing it with `innerHTML`?

Comment: tried it with `innerHTML` but the issue is not fixed

Comment: @Soolie yes i did check for errors in console but there were no errors.

Comment: @Ionut not good at explaining things in english i guess but the problem described above in my question is there. I have encountered it every time

Comment: On a sidenote, you should keep your logic and your interface separated. You don't have to parse the content of elements ever, just to set them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of timing. Updating the DOM just takes a bit longer then the code which is executed after you set the total score. That's why your alert shows nearly the same moment you wait for the DOM update.

Just use a timeout, then you'll see better what's happening.

```
function checkWin(currentPlayer) {
    setTimeout(() => {
       alert('Player '+ currentPlayer +' has won');
       resetGame();
    }, 1000);
}
```

(The alert prevents the re-rendering of your DOM and after the Alert the score is reset immediately, thus you see no changes)

And FYI: There's a little bug in your game: If you roll your dice and then keep pressing "Hold the score" you'll get the same points every turn.

Comment: or use requestAnimationFrame

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is an issue with the alert blocking the main thread, before the page has been updated.

To avoid this, try to place the checkWin function call into a window timeout, effectively decoupling the alert showing from the page update.

```
setTimeout(function(){checkWin(playerTurn)}, 10);
```

If you used an on-page alert (effectively showing the result in a div that would not block the page update) then you would be able to avoid this issue.